# Can't build project with latest XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I just updated XCode to the latest version to use the iOs 7.1 Simulator. Ever since I can't build the project anymore

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "VRightWebiOS::SetSecurityCallbackDelegate(id<VRSecurityCallback>)", referenced from:
      -[VXManager open:securityDelegate:] in VXManager.o
```

If  I try to build for device I get the same thing but with architecture arm7 instead of i386.
This didn't happen before the update and I have not modified the project file since...

Comment: You cleaned the project right? Also remove the derived folder then try building again.

Comment: I cleaned it 30 times... where do i find the derived folder?

Comment: deleted the derived data... This is the latest SDK that works with iOs 7.1 !

Comment: what is vmmanger class

Comment: because your app want some of framework. provide more detail about VMManager class

Comment: after update iOS 7.1 i faced same architecture i386 problem. i could solve add some framework regarding my app. it have solved

Comment: It's a third party drm library

Answer (score 6):

In the header (ViewRightWebiOS.h), try changing

`void SetSecurityCallbackDelegate(id<VRSecurityCallback> securityCallbackDelegate);`

to

`void SetSecurityCallbackDelegate(id securityCallbackDelegate);`

Xcode 5.1 seems to have changed the way the Objective-C++ source is linked.  Not sure how.

Comment: Helped! This answer must be approved.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following steps.It may solve your problem.
Goto build settings>Architecture>valid architecture and remove armv64 if present.Keep only armv7 and armv7s.

Comment: try to change the architecture to standard architecture(armv7,armv7s)

Comment: that option doesn't exist anymore... I tried to set them manually to armv7 and armv7s and it didn't work